# How to read a particular part of document in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, coding-style

I have a document as show in the picture. 
I want to retrieve the fileid, Author, and the description.
In some fileid, there is no description of the file. 
But in some fileid (i.e. fileid=3), there a description of the file. 
I want to know how can i get the desctiion in Python. 
Thank you.

```
start=re.compile('<file fileid=(\d+)\s*>')
end=re.compile('</file\s*>')

The Document starts from here:
--------------------------------------
<file fileid=11>
System File 765411
J.K
STAV December, 1959
</file>

<file fileid=12>
Batch File
James P.
STAV December, 1959
</file>

<file fileid=13>
Empty file
Person:Wolfe, P.
STAV December, 1959

This is a description of the empty file.
You need to put this file in the D:\location\systemB.
After putting the file to the location, the system will boot up.
Later, System B will refresh itself and show the output. 
</file>

<file fileid=14>
Nomal File
Mercy Lusia
STAV December, 1959
</file>
```

Comment: You've already written the regular expressions to do this, so… which part do you not know how to do?

Comment: I want to get something like:
ID: 13
Author: Wolfe, P
Date: December, 1999
Description: This is a description of ...

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way would be to read each line your file until you reach a line with

`<file fileid=xx>`.  Then read all the data until the closing `</file>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I would match the content that is between those tags as well; and then you can split by line break to receive the parts and the optional description.

```
>>> files = re.findall('<file fileid=(\d+)\s*>\s*(.*?)</file\s*>', s, re.S)
>>> for fileid, file in files:
        title, author, date, description = file.split('\n', 3)
        print(title)
        print(author)
        print(date)
        print(description.strip())
        print('----')

System File 765411
J.K
STAV December, 1959

----
Batch File
Person: James P.
STAV December, 1959

----
Empty file
Person:Wolfe, P.
STAV December, 1959
This is a description of the empty file.
You need to put this file in the D:\location\systemB.
After putting the file to the location, the system will boot up.
Later, System B will refresh itself and show the output.
----
```

You could then even create a dictionary of your documents:

```
documents = {}
for fileid, file in files:
    title, author, date, description = file.split('\n', 3)
    documents[fileid] = { 'title' : title, 'author' : author, 'date' : date }
    if description.strip():
         documents[fileid]['description'] = description.strip()
```

Comment: Thank you but I have problem with this line

files = re.findall('<file fileid=(\d+)\s*>\s*(.*?)</file\s*>', s, re.S)

I think it needs 2 args but there is an error at s

Comment: `s` would be the string that contains all the text. If you are reading from a file, you probably want to use `file.read()` there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already written two working regexps, let's start there.

You could just `start.split(document)`, then for each one, `end.split(the_one)[0]` is the contents of the `file` node.

Even more simply, just combine the start and end regexps, with a `(.*?)` in between, and now you've got a pattern that finds file nodes and gives you the `fileid` value and the contents. Just `rfile.find_all`, or `find_iter` so you can stop once you reach the one you care about.

Or, even more simply, just use a pattern that only searches for the one you care about, by replacing the `(\d+)` with a hard-coded number (or a `{}` that you fill in with `.format`).

Or, even more simply, drop the regexp entirely—`start` is a fixed substring up to the `\s*>`, so just use a plain substring search (like `str.index`) to find it, then do a substring search for the next `</file`, and everything between the outermost `>` and `<` is your contents.

If you're wondering how to run a regular expression or a plain substring search on a whole file, if it's small enough, `read` the whole thing into memory; if it's too big for that, `mmap` the file into virtual page space; if it's too big even for *that* (which is unlikely unless you're using 32-bit Python… but you could be), you will have to read in overlapping buffers instead.